# Remove all dots except its last occurrence

Tags: sql, string, oracle

I need regex to remove dots from a number, but not the last one.

What I'd like to do:

**100.000.10 -> 100000.10**

I tried with:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE ('100.100.10', '\.(?![^.]+$)|[^0-9.]','') FROM dual;
```

But it return 100.100.10

Comment: What type is the Column ?

Comment: It's a varchar2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need (slow) regular expression and can use (much faster) simple string functions:

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTR(value, 1, INSTR(value, '.', -1) - 1), '.')
       || SUBSTR(value, INSTR(value, '.', -1)) AS updated_value
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT '100.000.10' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| UPDATED_VALUE |
| --- |
| 100000.10 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Os3W-olK)